# How to test application based on Open GL ES 2.0?

Tags: android, testing, emulation, opengl-es-2.0, device

Will I be able to test my Open GL ES 2.0 application on Android Emulator? Or I will have to use Android 2.2 device to test it? What devices are best to test applications on it? I know that official Dev Phones are Nexus One and ADP 2 (as you can see on this website http://developer.android.com/index.html) but Im asking about your experience with other devices too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to test those applications only on real devices. Emulator doesn't support OGL ES 2.0. You can also use remote testing devices (look at Motodev Studio, there is some of support for this).
There is no noticeable differences between dev phone and "standard" phone, if you are application developer.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what's the best choice, cause there are so many devices now, and they just keep coming. Also you might think about testing your app on a tablet, if you consider designing for tablets, so here's a another problem of choice. Phones and tablets are very different in terms of performance, so you won't choose an ideal phone for testing. Testing on the emulator is also a waste of time with an OpenGL application, especially if it's dynamic, cause emulator will give you a very low FPS rate and very slow responsiveness.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - so android emulator is not an option. What will be difference between Android Dev Phone and normal Android Phone in case of testing?

Comment: Please check the piotpro's answer